# Does chrome.runtime.onInstalled fire when loading unpacked extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm testing out my chrome plugin and trying to test out `chrome.runtime.onInstalled`.

My code is as following

```
function installed(){
    alert("Success");
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(installed);
```

But when loading the extensions through `loading unpacked extension`. I don't get any alert at all. `chrome.runtime.onInstalled doesn't seem to fire. How can I test this?

The above code resides in `popup.js` and is called in a script tag from `popup.html`. The `manifest.json` file for that section looks like the following.

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "images/enabled-icon-19.png"
        //"38": "images/icon38.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "mytitle"
}
```

Comment: What you say "when loading", do you mean exactly loading a new unpacked extension, or reloading an already installed one?

Comment: I mean loading an unpacked extension. That is, it's not in the list of extensions. Once loaded, it is in the list of extensions. I'm not talking about reloading an already installed one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` to run you need to edit your `manifest.json` file and add

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

Put the `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(installed);` line there along with all the required functions. Then it will work as expected.

Comment: What did you previously do? The answer is not helpful if you don't explain what your mistake was.

Comment: I had it embedded as a script in popup.html.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify what I did earlier too.